# Qt w/ Cmake: set(QT_USE_QTWEBKIT TRUE) not working

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qtwebkit

I'm attempting to build a Qt-based application using cmake (It's what Kdevelop gave me). I tried to use a QWebView;

```
QWebView *webView = new QWebView( this );
webView->load(QUrl("http://google.ca"));
```

But it failed with Undefined Reference errors...

```
undefined reference to `QWebView::QWebView(QWidget*)'
undefined reference to `QWebView::load(QUrl const&)'
```

I looked it up and I needed to add QTWEBKIT to my project, but all the solutions said to add it to my .pro file... And I'm not using .pro. In the QT documentation it said to add "set(QT_USE_QTWEBKIT TRUE)" to my CMAKE file, this is my CMakeLists.txt file now:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Corrections Tool CMAKE list
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project(corrections)


# Versioning Requirements
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)


# Include QT Librtaries
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(QT_USE_QTWEBKIT TRUE)


# Set Sources
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(corrections_SRCS corrections.cpp main.cpp utilities.cpp prettySplash.cpp)


#The Rest
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
qt4_automoc(${corrections_SRCS})
add_executable(corrections ${corrections_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(corrections ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS corrections RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

But I'm still getting the errors, so either I did it wrong, in the wrong place, etc. I've also cleaned out and reconfigured my project several times making sure I wasn't using a bad generated makefile.

How would I either fix my cmake config to actually work, or convert my project to using .pro (with minimum stress & heartache)?

Thank you.

Comment: I normally use ${QT_LIBRARIES} instead of ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to select Qt components in CMake is to specify the them in the `find_package` call and then to include `${QT_USE_FILE}`

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 COMPONENTS QtWebKit REQUIRED )
INCLUDE( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

...


TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( corrections ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

This already configures the include directories and sets `${QT_LIBRARIES}` to contain all *relevant* Qt libraries (i.e. your selected component and all Qt libraries it depends on).
So you don't need to manually add the libraries by listing them individually as you did in your example.

*Edit:
Additional explaination:*
The `COMPONENT`parameter to `FIND_PACKAGE` actually does the same as your manual call to set `QT_USE_WEBKIT`. But this variable is only evaluated/used in `UseQt4.cmake` which is included (and "executed") by the `INCLUDE`command. See [CMake documentation of FindQt4](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindQt4) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be linking against all of the Qt libraries. Use ${QT_LIBRARIES} instead of ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} in your target_link_libraries

```
target_link_libraries(corrections ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: I just tried this, and now everything (Qt) has the undefined reference error. Hrm...

Comment: As Johannes S. said you are also missing an INCLUDE( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

Comment: Ah, didn't see his comment until just now. It's working!

Albut I'm slightly frazzled, I've been away from C++ for half a decade; rusty rusty rusty I am... Web development is too forgiving ;P